# ASP MVC Url Problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems with url validation using VB.NET ASP MVC4.

When I receive the parameter by url and this is really large I got this:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path,
>   file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be
>   less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248
>   characters.

How can I solve this error? or how can I show something friendly to the user considering UX?

[image: URL Example]

Comment: your probably saving the project in a place deep down.. as the error says your file location needs to be less then 260 characters so put the project on your desktop and run it again should work (unless your file names are huge)

Comment: For the page to ever be view-able by a user you must correct the error; not be too concerned with what error the user may see.

Comment: One thing I getting curious of: from where that long path with many zero numbers came along? Show your code to us which receives that number and origin of the number passed from.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I solve this error?

To solve this error, as suggested above, try to make your URL shorter.

> how can I show something friendly to the user considering UX?

To show some friendly message to the user, put try/catch block in your controller action method and in the catch block once the exception occurred put some messages in the object like viewbag and send it to the view for showing to the user.

Answer (score -1):

The error is very clear: `The specified path, file name, or both are too long.` It's meaning is very easy to understand.

You must make your URL shorter.  You've got a very long number `524000.....` in the URL that makes it too long.

You just need to use a shorter number in the URL.